# UML diagram tool with beautiful output

Tags: uml, diagram

Is there any UML tool that enables nodes styling? For example, setting not only the background colour for the "Class" node but also paddings, custom text alignment, different font settings of class name and attributes etc.

I like the functionality of **yEd** designer, but when I need to share a part of my model as a picture, it looks really poor.
Re-making the same diagram in a pure graphic editor is an overkill.

Comment: Have you tried MagicDraw? It does a lot of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some pretty automatic (not hand drawn) diagrams, then MS Visio is your choice. They even support [3D objects modelled by you](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2013/09/24/learn-to-create-3-d-shapes-in-visio/). But don't forget that Visio is not a fully strict modelling tool. It is pretty, but checks only some ties and rules. (It is not at all always bad, though)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at Papyrus. Not only do you have a log of control from within the tool, you can also use CSS externally to affect the rendition of the diagrams.

Comment: Yes, the Papyrus is very powerful and allows to set practically everything. It is useful for setting some original set of styles and colors consistently for the large project. On the other hand, if you want to create pretty diagrams, not creating a new set of standards, that tool is excessively complicated. Extremely complicated, I would say.

Comment: There are really two access levels within Papyrus: user and toolsmith. Of course, the latter is rather complex and not for everyone. User-centric capabilities are found in menu items, preferences; CSS and context menu  and the properties 
If you have issues with the user-centric capabilities, I would suggest you and anyone for that matter, bring them up  in the Papyrus forum - Papyrus's industry consortium team welcomes such feedback!